# MongoDB : how to get all elements that contain an array using Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

How would you write this MongoDB query using Java driver :

> db.customers.find({'arrayName' : {$exists:true}, $where:'this.arrayName.length>0'})

Cheers,
Yann

Comment: I would not use this query - it's a bad idea to use $where. Do a regular find with {arrayName.0:{$exists:true}}

Comment: Did you have a look at the [API doc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/)? Maybe you should be more precise if something there is not clear to you or does not work when you try.

Answer (score 1):

To build a query with the Java driver, you substitute any Javascript objects with `DBObject`'s.

```
DBObject condition = new BasicDBObject();
condition.put("arrayName", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));
condition.put("$where",  "this.arrayName.length>0");

DBCursor result = yourDatabase.getCollection("customers").find(condition);
```